# PHP array_rand / Loop / array_push / implode behavior?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Why does this not make two arrays one within 7 numbers and one within 2 numbers in it?

It somehow combines the both into one.

When i echo `$arvottuLottoRivi` and `$lottoLisaNumerot` in my HTML page the result is:

`$arvottuLottoRivi (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) : $lottoLisaNumerot`

all the seven numbers.

I have now tried three different styles but same thing happens in all cases

```
    // VARAIBLES
    $lottoNumerot = $_POST["lottoNumerot"];
    $mahdollisetNumerot = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39");
    $i = 0;
    $l = 0;
    $k = 0;


    //ARRAYS
    $arvottuLottoRivi = array();
    $lottoLisaNumerot = array();
    $tenNumbersArray = array();


    //FUNCTIONS
    $numeroidenRandomointi = array_rand($mahdollisetNumerot, 10);


    // COUNTS ARRAY LENGHT
    $lottoRivinPituus = count($numeroidenRandomointi);;

    // LOOPS
    foreach($numeroidenRandomointi as $randomNumero){
        while($i <= $lottoRivinPituus){
        $i++;
        }
        $randomToArray = array_push($tenNumbersArray, $randomNumero);
    }


    // LOOPIT
    foreach($tenNumbersArray as $randomToSite){
        while($l <= $lottoRivinPituus){
        $l++;
        }
        if($l <= 7){
            array_push($arvottuLottoRivi, $randomToSite);
        }
    }

    foreach($tenNumbersArray as $randomToSiteLisanuimerot){
        while($k <= $lottoRivinPituus){
        $k++;
        }
        if($k >= 7){
            array_push($lottoLisaNumerot, $randomToSiteLisanuimerot);
        }
    }

    $arvottuLottoRivi = implode(' ', $arvottuLottoRivi);
    $lottoLisaNumerot = implode(' ', $lottoLisaNumerot);
```

Comment: What's the point of those `while` loops?

Comment: @Barmar ooh Sorry I had `array_push`function there before. At the moment they do not have any function.

Comment: When I run your script, `$arvottuLottoRivi` is empty and `$arvottuLottoRivi` has 10 random elements of the input array.

Comment: @Barmar Ye I have the same result. I will fix the my writing. But it should be `$arvottuLottoRivi` = 7 numbers and  `$arvottuLottoRivi` = 2 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
foreach($tenNumbersArray as $randomToSiteLisanuimerot){
    while($k <= $lottoRivinPituus){
    $k++;
    }
    if($k >= 7){
        array_push($lottoLisaNumerot, $randomToSiteLisanuimerot);
    }
}
```

the `while` loop is equivalent to:

```
    $k = $lottoRivinPituus + 1;
```

Since `$lottoRivinPituus` is 10, `$k` is always 11. Therefore, `if($k >= 7)` is always true, so all elements of `$randomToSiteLisanuumerot` are copied to `$lottoLisaNumerot`. Similarly, in the previous loop, the test `if ($l <= 7)` is always false, so nothing is copied to `$arvottuLottoRivi`.

I think you were trying to test the current position in the loop, not the count of all elements in the array. You can do it like this:

```
foreach($tenNumbersArray as $l => $randomToSite){
    if($l < 7){
        array_push($arvottuLottoRivi, $randomToSite);
    }
}
foreach($tenNumbersArray as $k => $randomToSiteLisanuimerot){
    if($k >= 7){
        array_push($lottoLisaNumerot, $randomToSiteLisanuimerot);
    }
}
```

But this wastes time iterating over elements it doesn't care about. A better way would be:

```
$arvotSize = min(7, $lottoRivinPituus);
for ($l = 0; $l < $arvotSize; $l++) {
    array_push($arvottuLottoRivi, $tenNumbersArray[$l]);
}
for ($k = $arvotSize; $k < $lottoRivinPituus; $k++) {
    array_push($lottoLisaNumerot, $tenNumbersArray[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really didn't get your code.

Why don't use *rand* function?

```
$randomNumbers1 = array();
$randomNumbers2 = array();


$i = 0;
while ($i < 7) {
    $aNumber = rand(1, 39);
    if (!in_array($aNumber, $randomNumbers1)) {
        $randomNumbers1[] = $aNumber;
        $i++;
    }
}

$i = 0;
while ($i < 2) {
    $aNumber = rand(1, 39);
    if (!in_array($aNumber, $randomNumbers2)) {
        $randomNumbers2[] = $aNumber;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

And if the seconds array cannot contains any number within the first one:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 2) {
    $aNumber = rand(1, 39);
    if (!in_array($aNumber, $randomNumbers2) && !in_array($aNumber, $randomNumbers1)) {
        $randomNumbers2[] = $aNumber;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this technique, but I had some problems, it gives me the number 0, and I do not understand why. then I began to try a new way to create that.

Comment: Do you know how rand function works? 
*int rand ( int $min , int $max )*, but if you don't give any arguments, it will give you a number between 32768 and 0. EDIT: Also, I've found out you can try mt_rand() that is better function, if you need more stability, but I'm not the better person to tell you the significant differences between them.

Comment: Ye I gave it `rand(1, 39)`. I tried your code but almost the same happens. It just echoes the same numbers to both. I added `$arvottuLottoRivi = implode(' ', $randomNumbers2);`and `$lottoLisaNumerot = implode(' ', $randomNumbers2);`

Comment: You're giving both variables the same array. You should give $randomNumber1 to the $arvottuLottoRivi and $randomNumber2 to $lottoLisaNumerot or whatever one should recieve the seven array and the two array.